# does anyone know why my code, specifically the javascript wont run?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

My code doesn't seem to be running and it says that line 15 of my javascript (i.e. for loop) has an unexpected token.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title> Lab 7 Part 2 </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <canvas id= "drawingSurface"
           style="border-style: solid"
           width= "500" height="500"></canvas>
    <script src ="lab7b.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload= "setup();">
    <h1> Cat Mover </h1>

<input id ="up" type ="button" value="Up" onclick="upHandler()" >

<input id ="down" type ="button" value="Down" onclick="downHandler()">


<input id ="left" type ="button" value="Left" onclick="leftHandler()">


<input id ="right" type ="button" value="Right" onclick="rightHandler()">


<input id ="reset" type ="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetHandler()">
<section id="output">Move The Cat!<section>
</body>
```

my javascript file which seems to not work so can someone help me please?

```
var N, M, r;
var drawSurface;
var ctx;
var coordinates;

function setup(){
drawSurface= document.getElementById("drawingSurface");
ctx = drawSurface.getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(300,300);
}

function GenerateXY(M,N,r){
    coordinates = [[10,10],[[20,20]]

    for(var i = 0; i ,= M; i += 1;){
        var r2 = Math.abs(sin(angle*N/2));
        var x = r2*Math.sin(angle);
        var y = r2*Math.cos(angle);

        coordinates(i) = [x,y];

    }
    return coordinates;
}

function drawShape(){
    var numPetals = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    var numPoints = document.getElementById("text2").value;
    coordinates = getCoordinates(numPetals,NumPoints, 300);
    draw(coordinates);      
}

function draw(list){
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length, i+= 1){
        ctx.lineTo(list[i][0], list[i][1]);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

If you see the problem can you point it out and let me know if there is anything wrong and why it is wrong

Comment: What's `angle`? Pops up out of nowhere without being defined.

Comment: Should `var r2 = Math.abs(sin(angle*N/2));` rather be this `var r2 = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle*N/2));` ...?

Comment: You mean this part: `for(var i = 0; i ,= M; i += 1;){` ? Did you mean `i <= M`?

Comment: `i ,= M;` is it valid.? I don't know any expression similar to that.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[10,10],[[20,20]] 
         ^^
```

remove a [

```
[[10,10],[20,20]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two syntax errors in your top for loop. I guess the `,=` should be `<=`. And you probably want to access `coordinates` at index `i`, which is done with `coordinates[i]`.

```
for(var i = 0; i <= M; i += 1;){
    var r2 = Math.abs(sin(angle*N/2));
    var x = r2*Math.sin(angle);
    var y = r2*Math.cos(angle);

    coordinates[i] = [x,y];
}
```